# How can I convert English form of number to its Arabic number form in Perl?

Tags: perl, numbers

I need a Perl script which takes word form of number as input example **six** and it should give output as **6**. Is it possible in perl?

Comment: What is the maximum value of your input?

Comment: `my %h; @h{qw(one two three four five six)} = 1..6; print $h{six}`

Comment: Then you could easily create a lookup hash.

Comment: can you suggest me any cpan module if available

Comment: is this what you need https://metacpan.org/pod/Lingua::EN::Numbers ?

Comment: dwana i need english to number conversion but you have given number to english

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/release/JOEY/Lingua-EN-Words2Nums-0.18/Words2Nums.pm

Comment: Сухой27 thanks a lot i got what i wanted